# Measuring the similarity between distance vectors

Tags: machine-learning, regression, computational-mathematics, correlation, wasserstein

I am trying to measure the correlation between a probability distribution and a scalar value. For instance, I have the following:

| Vector of values | Corresponding Scalar |
| --- | --- |
| Vec 1 | Scalar 1 |
| Vec 2 | Scalar 2 |
| ... | ... |
| Vec n | Scalar n |

What I currently do is that, I calculate the wasserstein distance between each pair of vectors and calculate the difference between each pair of corresponding scalars, so the resulting is:

| Wasserstiein Distance (x,y) | Scalar Difference(x,y) |
| --- | --- |
| wass(vec1, vec2) | scalar1 - scalar2 |
| wass(vec1, vec3) | scalar1 - scalar3 |
| ... | ... |
| wass(vec n-1, vec n) | scalar n-1 - scalar n |

Then I calculate the correlation between these two streams (wass values) and (diff values). I use five different correlation coefficients to catch both linear and non-linear relations:

1. Peasron's Coeff.
2. Kendall Tau
3. Spearman
4. Distance Correlation.
5. Maximal Information.

The results suggest some correlation between the wasserstein distance and the corresponding scalar vector.

My question is: Is this correlation process legit? Is there any references I can look into utilizing the same concept?

Edit:
Regression is not possible in this context because the size of the vectors are not equal, so, this is a deficient data. Additionally, I don't have enough samples (vectors) for training a regression model.

That's why I am trying to avoid regression in this context.

Comment: First, this is exactly what regression is meant for. However, if you don't want regression but some measure of "correlation" you'll first need to describe what kind of correlation you are looking for? Here you are implicitly assuming a linear relationship between Wasserstien distance and the associated scalar (i.e., this is linear regression in disguise)

Comment: @Bey : I added more information to the question. The problem with regression is that, the size of each vector is not the same, which makes the training features a problem. I am looking into adding other features to indicate whether a feature is present or not (2n features instead of n) to solve this problem, but still not sure of the outcomes.